# Что не так в тернарном операторе?

Tags: c++, тернарный-оператор

```
cout << tree->BalanceCheck() ? "True" : "False";
```

Метод BalanceCheck возвращает либо true, либо false. Ошибка в том что cout выводит постоянно либо 1, либо 0. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << (tree->BalanceCheck() ? "True" : "False");
```